# HTTP request with XML payload using UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

Is there a way to submit an XML payload with the Google Apps Script `URLFetchApp`?

I have already tried adding the XML document to the payload

```
var url = "https://stackoverflow.com"; //not real
var xml = ///some xml

var params = {'content-type': 'application/xml',
              'method': 'post',
              'payload': xml};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
```

I am expecting the request to be submitted, but it errors out at the "fetch".

The error I receive is:

> "Attribute provided with invalid value: payload (line 73, file "Code")".

Comment: Cesar, could you please provide us with some info on what API you are trying to send XML payload to and what is the smaple value of `xml` - is it a xml string or a parsed document? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Problem**

You are passing an invalid second argument to the `fetch()` method call.

**Solution**

There is a closed set of acceptable parameters that you can pass in the configuration object. Please, make sure that names of the parameter *are exactly the same as in the reference* (see below). In your case, `content-type` should be renamed to `contentType` (currently, your request sends your XML document as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

Consider using a `muteHttpExceptions` set to `true` to ease debugging process in the future.

**Update**

After some more thorough investigation, the error you are experiencing is highly likely to be related (though previous issue still stands) to passing a *parsed* XML document (e.g. created via `XmlService`) to the `payload` if that is what you are doing (the error is reproduced consistently under this condition). Note that `payload` can accept either a `String` or `byte[]` or `Blob` instance or `Object` (varies on `contentType` parameter).

**Modification**

As per Tanaike's comment and suggestion, if you are indeed trying to pass a `Document` instance to the `payload`, the issue will be amended by preparing the XML (note that these operations don't mutate `xml` value), for example:

1. `XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(XmlService.parse(xml))`;
2. `XmlService.getRawFormat().format(xml)` (if XML is already parsed);

**Useful links**

1. `fetch()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object));
2. `XmlService` class [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service);
3. `getRawFormat()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service#getrawformat) (just in case);

Comment: Thanks, @Tanaike! I am pretty sure this is the root cause of the issue, let's see if that helps

Comment: Btw, @Tanaike, I stand corrected - the issue is caused by an invalid payload type instead (most likely, by trying to pass it a parsed `Document` instance - testing results in exactly that error and the invalid parameter `content-type` would then send it as a form-encoded string)

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. From your additional information, for example, how about adding `'payload': XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(XmlService.parse(xml))` as a modification point? Also, if it can know about the specification of the API and a sample XML value, it might be able to propose more modification points.

Comment: @Tanaike, agreed (and thank you for the suggestion, added yours and mine versions to the answer) - API info and XML value, though, depends on the author of the question