# Exception: Invalid argument at the time of UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script, curl, httprequest, urlfetch

I'm a beginner and I'm creating a function to list my products from an api.

The product insertion worked fine, but when mounting the GET I always get the message:

> Exception: Invalid argument at the time of UrlFetchApp.

In the api documentation they ask me to use the following url:

```
curl -X GET "https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/produtos/json/"
 -G
 -d "apikey={apikey}"
```

But I don't think I know how to implement this.

In the insert, just the simple URL worked...
(`const url = 'https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/produto/json/?apikey=MyKeyHere';`)

If you can give me any tips, that would be great.

```
function listaproduto() {

const url = 'curl -X GET "https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/produtos/json/" -G -d apikey=IPutTheKeyHere';



    const xml = {

     xml: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><produto><codigo></codigo><descricao></descricao><tipo></tipo><situacao>Ativo</situacao></produto>'

   };

    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        followRedirects: true,
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        payload: xml,
};


     const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
     Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Comment: In your showing curl command, `xml` is not used. So I cannot understand the specification of the API you want to use. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: The `url` does not look correct. There is a `/` that should not be there. Try `const url = "https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/produto/json?apikey=MyKeyHere"`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59924441/1595451, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67038738/1595451

Answer (score 0):

When you use the UrlFetchApp class you are not running a command like you do in the command line. Instead you are creating an object with pieces of information that together make up the same request you execute in the command line.

More documentation about this class can be found on this page https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app with a few examples.

In your code sample you entered the entire command as the URL that UrlFetchApp should fetch. Instead you need to put the URL alone, like you did in your example.

curl and UrlFetchApp are different solutions so they may not be capable of achieving the same result.
Similarities:

- The **-X** in the command line is the same as the url parameter for UrlFetchApp. *(Where you are getting the error message. @Mushroomator suggestion should address the problem)*
- The **-G** in the command line that specifies that all data in **-d** to be used in a HTTP GET request is the same as setting `method: 'GET'` in the arguments for this call.
- Data in **-d** is added in the `payload`.

I recommend you review the documentation and adjust your command current implementation with UrlFetchApp documentation. It is not very clear how the URL you visit needs to be received that XML data, you will find information on how to upload the data as a binary file, details on how to add XML data as request payload you can check this other question: [HTTP request with XML payload using UrlFetchApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263184) where @Tanaike commented and contributed with the answer.